# Bigquery: Retrieve information given unique combinations

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Currently I have the following R data.table object with product/cities combinations:

```
product_code       place
product1_code      city1
product2_code      city1
product3_code      city1
product4_code      city1
product1_code      city2
product6_code      city2
product9_code      city3
```

What I would like to do is to pass the previous product_code/city combinations to a query string and then pass it to bigrquery. Something like the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM my.table
WHERE city AND product_code in (list.with.unique.previous.combinations)
```

However I don't any idea of how I can pass the unique combinations as a list so it only retreives the information for those specific combinations. I know that I can use `glue` library to pass single elements to the query string something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM my.table
WHERE city = {city.selected} AND product_code = {product.code.selected}
```

but that would only work for 1 combination.

If anyone could give me an idea of how I could pass the entire list of combinations I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below example should give you an idea of how it is to be achieved in BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH combinations AS (
  SELECT 'product1_code' product_code, 'city1' place UNION ALL
  SELECT 'product2_code', 'city1' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'product3_code', 'city1' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'product4_code', 'city1' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'product1_code', 'city2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'product6_code', 'city2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'product9_code', 'city3' 
)
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
WHERE (city, product_code) IN (
  SELECT AS STRUCT place, product_code 
  FROM combinations
)
```

As you can see you need to combine `city` and `product_code` into STRUCT - `(city, product_code)` and look for it in list of combinations presented also as a struct via `SELECT AS STRUCT place, product_code FROM combinations`